# javascript functions available via javascript_include_tag but not asset pipeline and application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, asset-pipeline

My apologies if this has been posted somewhere else, but I'm not exactly sure how to even phrase a search for this problem.

Basically, I've got `fullcalendar.js` sitting in `app/assets/javascripts/`. Within my `application.js` file (in the same folder of course) I've got the following...

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
```

So, as expected the `fullcalender.js` gets swept up in the asset compiling process and ends up in the `application.js` that is then served to the user.

The problem comes in when I try to reference a function defined in `fullcalendar.js` (and thus defined in `application.js` after compiling the assets) it throws an error stating `TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function` in the js console of firebug, and of course full calendar doesn't render.

Now, however, if I include `<%= javascript_include_tag "fullcalendar.js" %>` in the layout file after all of the other scripts and stylesheets have been pulled in, it works as expected.

Baffled, I looked into the js in each file and compared them and can't see a difference. Is there something going on with the asset pipeline that I'm not aware of or is this some freaky DOM issue? I just have no idea at this point.

For reference, here are the contents of both the `application.js` and `fullcalendar.js` that are linked to in the page source of the site. I've only included the relevant full calendar portion of each, as it's too large for gist or pastebin if I include everything.

What baffles me is that both the sources come from the same file, one is just linked to directly, the other flows through the asset pipeline process.

`application.js` - http://pastebin.com/byyNErB8

`fullcalendar.js` - http://pastebin.com/k4p29YmP

Any insight or help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a dependency error. I'll suggest you to use a better practice for such lib.

1. Put the fullcalendar scripts into `vendor/assets/javascripts`
2. Require this script manually in application.js before the tree and after jquery and any other lib it depends.

   ```
   /=require 'fullcalendar`
   ```

**Add**

Check the loaded Javascript files in header, if application.js is the last, you have dependency error. The lib must be there before calling it.

Comment: Yeah, so, I did have it in my `vendor/assets/javascripts` section but to remove any further moving parts I temporarily moved it to the `app/assets/javascripts` section. I get the same results whether I leave the file in the vendor or app section :(

But yes, to be clear, you are totally correct in that they are best placed in the vendor folder.

Comment: @detectivist, I think the problem is you load the lib before the calling script. You can try remove `require tree` and require each file manually, putting your own scripts at the last.

Comment: Let's say I've got a little script that references a function that is defined in the lib. Don't I need to have that lib loaded before my script attempts to call that function? Right now, my own script, which calls to that lib is loaded after the lib itself is loaded. I assume this is what you mean.

Comment: @detectivist, yes, you are totally right. But I have not seen such custom code in application.js http://pastebin.com/byyNErB8

Comment: the addition to your comment got me thinking. It turns out the problem was that I was loading my script before jquery was loaded. So, just moving around the javascript_include_tags so that jquery loaded before the compiled application.js fixed the issue.

Thanks for getting me down the right path!