# Rails 5 assets pipeline not working as expected (Development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

am adding all my `.js` and `.css` files to precompile like this

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', 'application.scss', '*.scss', '*.css.erb']
```

And including `application.js` in layout `head` section like this

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

even though some of the `, js` files not available at my views. I have a file called `image-picker.js` in that directory. which make a `.imagepicker()` function available at my views but it's throwing an error like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imagepicker is not a function
```

But when i include that `.js` file for the page specifically using
`<%= javascript_include_tag "image-picker" %>`

it's working as expected. Why this is happening. Do I need to set anything else in the configuration? How to avoid including my assets at each page view??

**Update**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require image-picker.js #tried but not working.
//= require_tree .
```

**Update2**

am using `jquery-rails - 4.3.1` and `jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1`
which adding `jquery-2.1.4.min.js` to my assets. But when i use `//= require jquery` i think it's not including jquery to app.

When i tried adding it manually everything works properly,

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-2.1.4.min #now everything working fine. it seems a dependency problem.
//= require image-picker.js #tried but not working.
//= require_tree .
```

I would like to know what is the reason for this. thanks.

Very similar question you can find - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940208/javascript-functions-available-via-javascript-include-tag-but-not-asset-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

try to add `image-picker.js` in `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require image-picker
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: add `require_tree .` at the end of your `application.js` if it is not there.

Comment: it,s there. @PeterTretyakov

Comment: Updated please have a look @puneet18

Comment: @Nani `require image-picker.js` in `application.js`

Comment: @puneet18 I tried before posting question and restarted server too. It's not working. One more thing, when we include `required_tree` it will take all `.js` files in the same directory right? What is the use of adding again?

Comment: @Nani the order of file requiring matters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156977/discussion-between-nani-and-puneet18).